# What is wrong with this simple CSS in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border, margin

There is a div that has inner content, a div with a border that's inside a div.  Somehow, this div is expanded to encompass the next div.  It blows my mind.

```
<div style="background: yellow;">
  <div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black; background: green">green background</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 100px;">
  IE gives me a yellow background, unless i take away the border of the green 
  background div.
</div>
```

I'm wondering the cause of this and how to solve it.

Comment: I dont get the effect you are trying to get. Try describing that, then it might be easier to help. Especially the first child div do not make much sense since it has no styling at all.

Comment: I'm trying to next comments, with each child having a left border.  For some reason, that border gets "bled" down to all other children throughout the page.

Comment: Um, exactly *which* version of IE are you using? Perhaps you could edit your post including the full version as reported by IE's Help -> About menu.

Comment: 3 questions: 1.) is this in IE6, 7 or 8? 2.) do you have a doctype set, 3.) do you have a live url we can peek at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "give layout" to the first div. You better do this using IE6 targeted styles:

```
<style>
   * html .haslayout {
       display:inline-block;
   }
</style>

...

<div style="background: yellow;" class="haslayout">
```

This is a known IE6 issue with the hasLayout attribute. Read more on it here - http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

Comment: FF and IE-trans do different things with that inline-block though. Though I think it's better to fix the problem not the symptom, you're quite correct and haslayout could be more easily given with zoom:1.0; if the OP really can't use strict.

Comment: I've modified it to use IE6 specific rules

Comment: not a fan of conditional rules? (Not nitpicking, I'm not sure about best-practice myself)

Comment: I'm not a fan of using multiple stylesheets. This rule targets IE6 only and solves the problem

Comment: hasLayout seems to be the source of a lot of IE bugs, this included, and this presents a nice handy way to add "layout" to any element.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're in transitional quirksmode which is EVIL.

Strict solves this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Tried it out... put it in before <html> and it's still broken.

Comment: +1 but just adding there's a range of doctypes that will take you out of quirks mode http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode

Comment: That's all... just the doctype and <html><body>[what i wrote]</body></html>

Comment: caching? try it in a new html doc?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to put "position: relative" everywhere, but this breaks other things in my page.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon in the inner div. I have seen some very weird behaviour if the last semicolon is omitted.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; background: green;">green background</div>
```

Not sure what version of IE you have, but this works in IE7

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>  
  <body>
    <div style="background: yellow;">
     <div>
        <div style="border: 1px solid black; background: green;">green background</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 100px;">
      IE gives me a yellow background, unless i take away the border of the green 
      background div.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is verry easy, because you nesting diverent div's, and none off them has a height, so there is a overflow for IE6.
do this:

```
<div style="background: yellow;height: 1%;">
```

and it will work just fine.